# PendingIntent does not create intent chooser

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I am using Chrome custom tabs to open URL in my application. I am trying to configure `Share` feature in its action button which requires PendingIntent as one of its arguments. I am returning the PendingIntent as follows:

```
private static PendingIntent getShareIntent(@NotNull Context context, @NotNull Uri uri)
{
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, uri.toString());
    return PendingIntent
        .getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(),
            shareIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```

The problem is that when the share button is clicked the first time, it creates a chooser (shown below) to select application to be used for sharing, but does not do it after the first time. This is shown just once. After user has made a choice, that becomes the default application and all subsequent clicks on share button opens in the application selected the first time. I have used `Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via")` while returing pendingIntent, but to no avail. Please help.

[image: Intent Chooser]

Comment: let me clear it you just waana open application every time which as register intent-filter Intent.ACTION_SEND

Comment: No. I want the user to be able to choose from all applications which support opening that action (which in my case is 'text/plain').

Comment: why you are using pending intent ? you can do it with intent also

Comment: What happens from the second time? Does it open the last chosen application?

Comment: @KamranAhmed: yes, it opens the last chosen application.

Comment: @jiteshmohite: It is as per API provided by chrome custom tab: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#configure-a custom action button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it did not work on Samsung Note 3 Neo (SM-N750). It worked fine with Nexus devices I tested with. Wasted half a day trying to fix this. Such is life.

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted otherwise, people will keep coming to help.